# A filter to remove f0 and lower harmonics from the signal

Tags: digital-filters, speech-processing, pitch, speech

I'm studying the perception of vowel formants (resonances of the vocal tract) and need to create stimuli where the signal below the first (lowest) formant is removed. I have some synthesised vowels which have a dynamic pitch curve because they sound much more natural this way, which is important for the study. But having a non-flat pitch means that using a fixed threshold high-pass filter will leave more harmonics in some sections of the stimulus. I would like to avoid that.
I see a manual alternative: to cut the vowel sounds into bits that have a relatively flat pitch contour, filter them separately and then concatenate the bits back to original sequence. But I am reluctant to do this, because I have 280+ different vovel tokens and would like to have an automated and replicable process that other researchers could eventually use to validate the study.

Is there a way to specify a dynamic threshold for the filter, for example to make it follow a pre-determined f0 curve? Perhaps even removing some higher harmonics?

I'm using Praat, R, and have access to MatLab, but I'm not a good programmer, so I'd be extra thankful for any suggestions of methods that are either readily available or not too difficult to implement in these environments.

Thanks.

[image: The expected result of a dynamic f0-tracking filter]

Comment: Maybe you can find a solution from [here](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange?q=remove+harmonics).

Comment: Great suggestion @JuhaP, I see at least one [promising option](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/104555-digital-signal-processing-system-analysis-and-design?focused=b988de35-99f5-4f66-a67f-c014b9c170b1&tab=function). Thank you.